# WP-CLI search-replace posts content for certain URLs

Tags: wp-cli

Using WP-CLI I am wanting to search and replace posts content but only for certain URLs.

This is what I have so far:

```
$ wp search-replace 'Contact us today' 'Contact us today by filling in the form below' wp_posts --include-columns=post_content --dry-run
```

How can I adapt this command so that it only does the search replace on URLs within the products directory?

For example:

- https://www.example.com/products/product1/
- https://www.example.com/products/product2/
- etc.

Comment: How are you setting up the "products directory" -- is it an actual directory? a parent page? a custom post type?

Comment: @PatJ products directory is a parent page.